# How to Program Who wins in Euchre

Tags: python, rank, playing-cards, scoring

I'm working on programming the card game Euchre in python and the last piece I need to code in is a way to determine which player/team wins each hand. The way I've coded my program is that cards are represented by the first letter of their rank and suit. For example, the ace of spades is written as 'As' and a player's hand would be written as:

```
Player_hand=['9c','Qh','Jh','Js','10d']
```

Every round each player (four players in total) would play a card and then the winner is decided by whoever played the highest valued card. My problem with this is I cannot figure out how I can accomplish this. Can any of you think of a way that I could use to determine which player won each hand of cards played? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your problem determining which is the highest card in some collection, or something else?

Comment: Create a list which determines the in-suit rank and write a function that takes each player's card and the trump suit which yields the winner of that trick.  Do you need to create a player AI which would simulate good choices being made, or can you just take any random player card selections?  If the latter, the most complex part will be writing the function to determine the winner of a trick.